# Access instance from passed calllback

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a game in python that has items in it. The player can use items, and different items can do different things. Instead of making a bunch of subclasses for each item type, I'm passing a callback function upon initialization. However, in some cases I need to access the item instance from the callback function - this is where I'm stuck.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, use_callback, regen=0):
        self.use_callback = use_callback
        self.regen = regen

def heal(self, player):
    player.health += self.regen

item = Item(heal, regen=30)
item.use_callback(player)
```

However, only the player object is passed to the heal function and not the item object: `TypeError: heal() missing 1 required positional argument`
It's inconvenient for me to use subclasses since I'm using a table of item drops for each enemy which contains information about the items they drop  and it's easier to instantiate an Item upon death than figure out which subclass I need to instantiate.

Any ideas on how to get the reference to the item object?

Comment: You are using `self` as an argument for a non-class function, just take out the `self` and this should work fine, although you'll have to define `player` somewhere

Comment: I know it works without the self. I want to make it into a class function so I can access self.regen

Comment: The actual code is too big to put in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about wrapping the callback to pass in the object:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, use_callback, regen=0):
        self.use_callback = lambda *args, **kwargs: use_callback(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.regen = regen

def heal(item, player):
    if item.regen is not None:
       player.health += item.regen

item = Item(heal, regen=30)
item.use_callback(player)
```

[Example code](https://repl.it/repls/GrowingCarelessSymbol)

An alternate architecture I would put some thought to is having the Player object have a consume method. The advantage here is the complexity is taken out of your Item object. There is a probably slightly neater way to write this.

```
item = Item(effects=[(heal, regen=30), (gravity_boost, multiplier=2), (speed)])
class Player
    def consume(self, item):
        for effect in item.effects:
            callback = effect[0]
            **kwargs = effect[1:]
            callback(player, item, **kwargs)
```

Beyond this it might be worth considering a simple 'publish subscriber' system that would separate your objects so that they would not have cross dependencies. This will add architectural simplicity at the cost of some code complexity.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I will look into those recommendations

Comment: Happy to help. A rule of thumb for me is if you are starting to rely on callbacks & or lambdas - in python - its worthwhile just thinking a bit about your architecture. With pubsub things like 'double healing potion effects next to fountains' become trivial. Good luck with the game!